# ASP.NET Core with MVC iapplicationbuilder does not contain a definition for usemvc

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Building a .net core mvc app in VS Code and getting the error IApplicationBuilder does not contain a definition for UseMvc. Here are my dependencies in my project.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "platform"
},
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions": "1.0.0",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0"
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a goofed up dependency. Try changing this:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
```

to this:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
```

Comment: Didn't even notice that my MVC reference was AspNet instead of AspNetCore, duh! Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1):

Add this PropertyGroup to projectName.csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;
   </PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then close the solution and reopen it.